# Why can't I setup SSL server on Android successfully?

Tags: java, android, sockets, ssl

I am trying to setup one SSL Server Socket in my Android project. I refer many talks in stackoverflow and finally I initialize my Server Socket like following code

```
String type = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
KeyStore store=KeyStore.getInstance(type);
inputStream=this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("test.bks");
store.load(inputStream, password);
inputStream.close();
String keyalg=KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
KeyManagerFactory factory=KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(keyalg);
factory.init(store,password);
KeyManager []keyManagers=factory.getKeyManagers();
context=SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
context.init(keyManagers, null, null);
ServerSocketFactory factory= context.getServerSocketFactory();
serverSocket=(SSLServerSocket)factory.createServerSocket(12345);
while (true) {
    Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
    new ReceiveSocket(socket).start();
}
```

When the code step to `serverSocket.accept()`, it throws one exception:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Could not find any key store entries to support
    the enabled cipher suites
```

I try to debug one step by step and I found `keyManagers` seemed key issue. One of fields in `Keymanagers` named `EntrySet` is null while the similar pure Java code this `EntrySet` with one address. BTW the pure Java code is work correctly. I try to config the `keymanager` in different ways, but no happy ending.

Could someone give me some suggestions? Thanks a lot.

Some more information

1. the android min version is 8, the target is 19
2. this code is part of library in my whole big project
3. the certification should be OK, since i have another code to send SSL message using the same one. It works well.

Any missing, please tell me. Thanks again.

==================================================================

After tough day job, i sovled this issue. Firstly the question is caused by me. I did not undersatnd the SSL protocol completely, especially for ceritification file usage. I use the BKS file is public ceritification file for client, not private one for server. That is why the server can not setup.  Refer the Yaragalla's blog http://yaragalla.blogspot.jp/2013/05/how-to-create-ssl-serversocket-on.html. I get the BKS format private ceritification for my Android server side. Then i using follwing commands to get my BKS public ceritification file for my Android clinet side.

keytool -exportcert -file ServerKey.cert -keystore .\ServerKeystore -storetype BKS
keytool -importcert -keystore clientkey.bks -file ServerKey.cert -storetype BKS -provider org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider

Hope these useful for anyone with simiar issues.